# How is this "menu" called?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to implement this kind of "pop up menu" in my app but I have no idea how it is called and therefore I can't do any research on how to do it.

[This is the picture](https://lh6.ggpht.com/q4n4nPiurUTFDDBonKwnfJtywk95YDSOKwajjCC2Vqz-g644gQNz6Ba9jOmx3gLXKEA=h900-rw)

I want this menu to have three options, right now I'm using AlertDialog and the buttons are right next to each other (positive, negative, neutral), but I'd rather use this kind of pop up menu since it can have more buttons and looks more professional.

I'm not asking for the code or anything, I just want to know how this menu is called so that I can do my research then.

Comment: that looks like the ContextMenu for listviews

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

Comment: @Marcelo thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for, you can put it in an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [Context Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu). There are two options, a floating context menu (like the one on your image), or the contextual action mode (shows the options on an ActionBar, like the GMail app for example).

You can choose which one is more appropriate for your app, but the official documentation states:

> If you're developing for Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, you
>   should usually use the contextual action mode to present contextual
>   actions, instead of the floating context menu.

Answer (score 0):

User [Marcelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203983/marcelo) gave me an answer.

[This is what I was looking for](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)